# Regexp: Grouping in a group

Tags: regex, go

I am trying to match output from Nmap command using Regexp. There can be two different formats.

1st format (when nmap can find hostname)

```
Nmap scan report for 2u4n32t-n4 (192.168.2.168)
```

and 2nd format (without hostname)

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.2.1
```

I want to capture both hostname and ipaddress and if there is no hostname just get Ip as the hostname as in the 2nd format.

What I was trying in Regexp so far in golang is

```
Nmap scan report for\\s+([^[:space:]]+)(\\s+\\(([^[:space:]]+)\\))?
```

But what I got as a result in golang

The 1st format ( it gave me `(192.168.2.168)` which I don't want ) is as follow:

```
[Nmap scan report for 2u4n32t-n4 (192.168.2.168), 2u4n32t-n4 , (192.168.2.168) , 192.168.2.168]
```

and the 2nd format ( it gave me  which I don't want ) is as follow:

```
[Nmap scan report for 192.168.2.1, 192.168.2.1,  ]
```

What to do correctly?

Comment: Is it really a problem if you get the blank match? You could just loop through the matches and remove the blank match. Otherwise, I could fix the part with the unwanted match in 1st format.

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
Nmap scan report for\s+(?P<hostname>.*?)[\s,]
```

see it in [action](http://regex101.com/r/kY0uX0)